# Problem running Ubuntu9.10

Tags: installation, ubuntu-9.10

I have installed Ubuntu9.10 as Dual Boot using Wubi, everything worked perfect but after the installation completed the PC started freezing, I have reinstalled Ubuntu using the same Wubi, but things just don't work, it freezes after a few seconds. I really want to use Ubuntu so please help me out and I have the ISO file for Ubuntu, so any other option to install Ubuntu is welcomed. Also, here's some information about my PC configuration:

RAM: 512MB,
Currently Installed OS: Windows XP Service Pack 3,
Processor: Pentium 4

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not programming related. use serverfault.com

Answer (score -1):

I have Windows XP and Ubuntu 9.10 (about to upgrade) dual boot, but I don't use wubi... I installed Windows XP first, then Ubuntu and grub automatically detected my other partition and set up grub accordingly, now I use grub to pick the OS on boot.

I don't know if Wubi offers anything more than that, but my setup works flawlessly. If I ever lose my MBR for any reason, I just boot from the Ubuntu CD, and install grub again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: OH Please asking an irrelevant (non-programming question is bad enough). please don't encourage, this. Its not like no one wants to help its just that this isnt the place. See serverfault.com

Comment: Not really sure that "well, I did something different and it works for me" is useful...